# How to use view flipper with three layouts?

Tags: android, layout, view, android-activity

I am currently using `ViewFlipper` for my main activity with two different layouts.  I want to use a third layout, but I can only find the `showNext()` and `showPrevious()` commands. Can someone show me how to implement a third layout using `ViewFlipper`?

Comment: If you have 3 layouts in viewflipper, showNext() shows view sequentially, i.e. showNext() aftrer 2nd layout shows 3rd layout.

Comment: Try using this method: public void setDisplayedChild (int whichChild) to set your views.

Comment: Is it possible to go from the first view to second view back to first and then to third view?

Comment: Yes its possible. See the example I posted that displays the views in any order one wants.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Made an example for you that shows howto display different views in a ViewFlipper.

The layout of the example is made up of the following parts. There are three radio buttons. A ViewFlipper is placed below the radio buttons. This flipper holds three different simple views with different texts.

The radio buttons are then hooked up to a listener in the java code that will change the view displayed by the ViewFlipper depending on which radio button that currently is chosen.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio0" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show View 1" android:checked="true"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show view 2"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show View 3"></RadioButton>
    </RadioGroup>

    <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/ViewFlipper01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!--adding views to ViewFlipper-->
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="First view is now displayed"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Second view is now displayed"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Third view is now displayed"></TextView>
    </ViewFlipper>

</LinearLayout>
```

**JAVA**

```
package com.test.threeviews;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class ThreeViewsinaFlipperActivity extends Activity {

    RadioButton RB0;
    RadioButton RB1;
    RadioButton RB2;
    ViewFlipper VF;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /*
         * Find the views declared in main.xml.
         */
        RB0 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        RB1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        RB2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        VF = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper01);

        /*
         * Set a listener that will listen for clicks on the radio buttons and
         * perform suitable actions.
         */
        RB0.setOnClickListener(radio_listener);
        RB1.setOnClickListener(radio_listener);
        RB2.setOnClickListener(radio_listener);
    }

    /*
     * Define a OnClickListener that will change which view that is displayed by
     * the ViewFlipper
     */
    private OnClickListener radio_listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.radio0:
                VF.setDisplayedChild(0);
                break;
            case R.id.radio1:
                VF.setDisplayedChild(1);
                break;
            case R.id.radio2:
                VF.setDisplayedChild(2);
                break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 7):

See this simple use of [android.widget.ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html). With it you can create different layout from xml and then switch among them with simple method like this:

```
   ViewFlipper viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.myViewFlipper);

   // you can switch between next and previous layout and display it
   viewFlipper.showNext();
   viewFlipper.showPrevious();

  // or you can switch selecting the layout that you want to display
  viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
  viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(viewFlipper.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.secondLayout)
```

Xml example with tree layouts:

```
     <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/myViewFlipper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
               [...]
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
               [...]
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/thirdLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
              [...]
            </LinearLayout>
      </ViewFlipper>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use it in this way also. I have attached the java code and xml file where a button is used to change the flipper view.

```
package com.nikhil.play.add_subtract;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class Flipper extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ViewFlipper flippy;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_flipper);
        flippy = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
        flippy.setOnClickListener(this);
        flippy.setFlipInterval(10000);
        flippy.startFlipping();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        flippy.showNext();
    }

}
```

XML CODE-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Flipper 2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Flipper 3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Flipper 4" />
    </ViewFlipper>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

xml

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/viewflip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

Java

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment{
ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;

int gallery_grid_Images[]={drawable.image1, drawable.image2, drawable.image3,
        drawable.image1, drawable.image2, drawable.image3, drawable.image1,
        drawable.image2, drawable.image3, drawable.image1
};
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(fragment_blank, container, false);
    viewFlipper =(ViewFlipper)rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewflip);

    for(int i=0;i<gallery_grid_Images.length;i++)
    {
        //  This will create dynamic image view and add them to ViewFlipper
        setFlipperImage(gallery_grid_Images[i]);

    }

    return rootView;

}

private void setFlipperImage(int res) {
    Log.i("Set Filpper Called", res+"");
    ImageView image = new ImageView(getContext());
    image.setBackgroundResource(res);
    viewFlipper.addView(image);
    viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(1000);
    viewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);

}
```