# Is it possible to open a new layout(.xml) file with button click?

Tags: android

I have a `MainActivity.java` file with a single layout. I created a new layout that is simply called layout2, and want to call it somehow in the MainActivity.java file, to switch between the 2 layouts with a btn click, but without any .java class file (like in Activities: .java file goes with his own single layout).

For short:
An Activity open (just) a new layout file.

Thanks for any answers.

```
ImageButton ibtt;
ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibtt);
ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      MainActivity.setContentView(R.layout.secondlayout);
    }
});
```

Comment: call `setContentView()` again but probably not a good idea

Comment: The app crashes..

Comment: use fragments, instead of other activities

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to do but a Viewflipper sounds something you might like. Define a viewflipper with as many children as you want in the xml. The children can be separate layouts each. Use the`<include>` tag. Plenty of examples with viewflipper on StackOverflow. I prefer using a statekeeper along with one always.

EDIT: Here's an example [How to use view flipper with three layouts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869180/how-to-use-view-flipper-with-three-layouts)

Comment: This answer would be perfect if it linked to the documentation for ViewFlipper and/or some other SO questions about ViewFlipper.